# Combining two structures into new one on C?

Tags: c

So, we have an interesting situation.
We are supposed to write a DBMS in C under Linux and we have the following problem:
when trying to join two relations/tables the new relation/table has number of Fields/Columns equal to the sum of both joining relations/tables. This is fine, but when we have to copy the data of the tuple/row from the two joining relations/tables we don't seem to find a way. The tuples/rows are realized as list elements via this structure:

```
typedef struct element {
    void *data;
    struct element *next;
} Element;
```

The new element is created via this function:

```
Element *
newElement (void *data)
{
    Element *e = (Element*) malloc (sizeof (Element));
    assert (e != NULL);
    e->data = data;
    e->next = NULL;

    return e;
}
```

And the *data parameter is passed as of this type:

```
typedef struct {
    int sid;
    char sname[STRLEN];
    int rating;
    float age;
} Sailor;
```

The thing is when we have to join two relations we cannot know what Structure they use for their tuples/rows and therefore we cannot create the new tuples/rows for the new relation from the tuples/rows of the two joining relations.

Please help.

Comment: You are writing a DBMS in C?  Wow.  Do let us know how it goes.

Comment: Is this homework? If so,please consider tagging it as such.

Comment: I have no idea how DBMSs are implemented, But here are my 2 cents, May be you should be looking at a table as a collection of columns, each of which is an array , instead of looking at each row as data structure. That would make including a new column as simple as allocating a new pointer to it.

Comment: In C, don't cast the return value of malloc(). Doing so can hide bugs, and never makes anything better.

Answer (score 1):

Given you cannot at runtime define new structures, something like the following (hack?) could work..

Firstly define a base structure which only has a type id

```
typedef struct
{
  int type_id; /* this holds a number which identifies the following structure */
} TypeID;

/* now all structures should contain this */

typedef struct {
  TypeID type;
    char sname[STRLEN];
    int rating;
    float age;
} Sailor;

typedef struct {
  TypeID type;
  char sname[STRLEN];
  int sailors;
} Boat;
```

Now treat the data segment as a *container* of these structs, let's say for example that I will have two structs in data (i.e. joined the two above structs), my data segment would look like:

```
----------
| Sailor |
+--------+
|  Boat  |
----------
```

When reading the data chunk, first cast it to `TypeID`, which gives you the type, then you can cast it to the real structure. Then if there is more data in the data segment, move the pointer by the sizeof the structure you've just read, and again do the same process. Basically this allows you to have a variable length segment which is a set of structures of different types - i.e. your *joined* data structure.

Oh, and you'll need to modify your `Element` structure to hold the size of the data segment as well.

Comment: How would you dynamically cast into a certain struct at runtime ? Or did you mean a switch case statement with all possible types in it?

Comment: @Adham, I didn't say *dynamically cast*, I said *cast* to `TypeID`, which gives you the type (id), then you need to cast to the real type (i.e. using a `switch`, `if-else` whatever takes your fancy!)